# Azure SignalR to call an API with connect and disconnect events in azure portal

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-signalr

Is there any way to call a python API from the SignalR for connect and disconnect events? I need to call my API when a new client is connected using the SignalR service on azure.

Comment: You may try Python Azure function with SignalR trigger, Refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-python) which will help in get started with Azure SignalR Service by using Azure Functions and Python to build a serverless application that broadcasts messages to clients.